# Is there a way to visualise Contact Forces in 2D in drake?

Tags: drake

The inbuilt `ConnectPlanarSceneGraphVisualizer` is a handy tool when running simple experiments on 2D setups. I have found it very useful. I was wondering if there was a 2D version of this helper function to visualise contact forces as well. Is there any way of projecting the contact forces onto the visualizer window used by the `PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer`. Furthermore, more generally if I want to integrate `drake`'s setup with the handy `pyplot` functionality, how can I visualise the contact forces in 2D?

Thank you for your instruction and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's still an [open feature request](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13214). The reason it hasn't been resolved is because I've been moving everything to meshcat, and putting meshcat into ["2d render mode"](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_meshcat.html#a1464f94b8c5d602566dee2b83f47c5df). You can see contact forces there (and also get other meshcat benefits).

Comment: Thank you! If I had to implement it, is it as simple as connecting a similar `ConnectPlanarContactVisualizer` type system, connect the `contact_results` and use the same projection window and draw arrows for the contact? If it is, I can give it a shot.

Comment: That sounds right.  If you do, please consider contributing it back!